# How can I use unique_ptr in googleTest with inheritance in this scenario

Tags: c++, inheritance, googletest, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I am trying to learn C++, smart pointers and googleTest. I have a question about inheritance and google test.

I have a class named A

```
class A {
    public:
    A() {}
    virtual ~A() {}

    virtual void setSmtInA(int setSmt);
    virtual int getSmtInA(void);
};
```

And also I want to create C sub class inheriting A

```
class C {
    public:
    C(unique_ptr<A> upA) : pA(move(upA)) {
    virtual ~C() {}

    virtual void setSmtInC(int setSmt);
    virtual int getSmtInC(void);

    private:
    unique_ptr<A> pA;
};
```

And there is GoogleTest and in this test I want to access methods under C and also A.

```
TEST(Some_Tests, Test1) {
    unique_ptr<A> myA = make_unique<A>();
    C myC = C(move(myA));

    myC.setSmtInC(15);
    int temp = myA->getSmtInA();
    
    EXPECT_EQ(15, temp);
}
```

What is correct way/logic to do this?

I tried to understand the logic behind pointers but could not figure it out when inheritance comes into picture.

Comment: after you moved from `myA` why do you still want to use it?

Comment: frankly, it seems you are mxing too many things, inheritance, smart pointers, moving, gtest. Its not clear what the question is actually about. What exactly is "this" when you ask "What is correct way to do this?" ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number actually I want to understand dependency injection with unique_ptr and how to create a google test case to test.

Comment: `unique_ptr<A> myA = make_unique<A>(); auto& myAReg = *myA; C myC = C(move(myA)); ...` could be one way to go about this, but it does make some assumptions about how `C` handles the smart pointer. Iirc there's also the a friend_test or similarly named macro that would allow you to provide access to the internals of a class to certain tests...

Comment: I don't see any inheritance being involved here btw and using it wouldn't help you gain access to ***private*** members of `C`.

Comment: It appears you are mixing up *dependency injection* and *inheritance*, which are two different, distinct things.

Answer (score 2):

You have several ways to test with [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle)):

- your way, but fixed:

  ```
  TEST(Some_Tests, Test1)
  {
      std::unique_ptr<A> myA = std::make_unique<A>();
      A* Aptr = myA.get();
      C myC = C(std::move(myA)); // `myA` is now nullptr

      myC.setSmtInC(15);
      int temp = Aptr->getSmtInA();

      EXPECT_EQ(15, temp);
  }
  ```
- mocking `A`:

  ```
  struct MockA : A
  {
      MOCK_METHOD(void, setSmtInA, (int), (override));
      MOCK_METHOD(int, getSmtInA, (), (override));
  };

  TEST(Some_Tests, Test1)
  {
      std::unique_ptr<MockA> myA = std::make_unique<MockA>();
      EXPECT_CALL(*myA, setSmtInA(15));
      C myC = C(std::move(myA));

      myC.setSmtInC(15);
      // most checks are done at end of scope, when mock object is desroyed.
  }
  ```